# Как добавить кнопку "Все новости" при выводе новостей в Битрикс (news:list, ajax)?

Tags: битрикс

По условиям задачи сделал (по мануалу) вывод новостей с подгрузкой следующих (новостей) через ajax.

Реализовано через пагинацию, т.е. ссылка с кнопки "Еще новости" имеет вид /?PAGEN_1_2 и т.д.

Нужно добавить кнопку "Все новости", при клике на кот., раскроется весь список новостей. Какого вида ссылка должна быть у нее? Пробовал /?SHOWALL_1_2 и т.д., не помогает.

Comment: В настройках компонента раньше была возможность отметить чтобы такая ссылка выводилась. Просто так вписать ссылку это вы хорошо придумали. А как система должна понять что именно вы получить хотите? Напишите код который будет все записи и выводить их. А потом подвешивайте его выполнение хоть на кнопку, хоть на ссылку.

Comment: Галка отмечена http://joxi.ru/LmGEB3RCwRPnzA , только я совсем запутался, как ее вывести в шаблон

Comment: Это же стандартный функционал Битрикса - o-kompanii/novosti.php?PAGEN_1=3 переходим на 3-ю страницу пагинации

Comment: Если есть возможность в настройках компонента выставить просмотр всех новостей, то значит, можно перейти по определенной ссылке. По какой?

Comment: У кого-то есть сайты на Битриксе со стандартной кнопкой "Все"? Посмотрите, какой там get параметр

Comment: В настройках компонента можно указать определенный шаблон вывода пагинации. Вам вероятнее всего нужно найти файл вывода пагинации  изменить его. Там скорее всего все сслке хранятся в массиве, выведите массив и просмотрите его

Comment: Подключите дефолтный шаблон вывода новостей и дефолтный шаблон пагинации. Или посмотрите в код шаблона стандартный и перенесите в свой шаблон оттуда.